# Corrupt icon in Java notifications under Windows

Tags: java, windows, notifications, awt

When trying to display Windows message notifications with Java (I tried several OpenJDK versions from 11 to 21, by different vendors, and on multiple machines with Windows 10 or 11), the icon displayed on the message itself is corrupted, like so:

[image: Windows Notification with Corrupt Icon]

Here is some code to reproduce the problem:

```
package org.example;

import java.awt.*;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
      Dialog d = new Dialog(((Window) null), "Corrupt Icon Demo");
      d.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      d.setBounds(0, 0, 750, 500);
      d.setVisible(true);

      final Image normalImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("./Foo.png");
      d.setIconImage(normalImage);

      final SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
      final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(normalImage, "Corrupt Icon Demo");
      trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
      try {
        tray.add(trayIcon);
      } catch (AWTException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }

      trayIcon.displayMessage("Test", "Test", TrayIcon.MessageType.NONE);
    }
  }
```

The icon itself appears correctly both in the application window and in the Windows system tray but not in the toast notification itself.

[EDIT]

Under Windows 10 the item seemed only partially corrupted (in the lower half), while under Windows 11 it is entirely corrupted. (The icon in the image above is the corrupted Windows 11 version of a PNG converted from https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Public-domain-symbol.svg )

One suspicion I am having, based on a look at the OpenJDK WTrayIconPeer.java source code, is that the OpenJDK code does not scale the alpha transparency bitmask based on the scaling settings of Windows: TRAY_ICON_MASK_SIZE remains constant. (The source code does scale the icon based on that though.)

Am I overlooking something here or is this a bug in the OpenJDK implementations?

Comment: By "corrupt", do you mean it is looking completely different or that it is displaying incomplete?

Comment: In the above image it is totally corrupted, as I am using a public domain symbol from WIkipedia here. I've updated the question to that effect.